# Sorting strings with matching endings JS

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have an array with various strings in it:

```
let myArray = [
  "www.goal.com/kdñon-BigPussy", 
  "www.goal.com/qwñeorkfnvowv-Paulie", 
  "www.goal.com/woeknapffflmkub-Tony", 
  "www.goal.com/npylhyokhp-Silvio", 
  "www.goal.com/irjnfrfrn-Silvio"
];
```

As you see, every string ending is formatted like this: `-Name`.

What I want is to store the strings with the same ending (`www.goal.com/npylhyokhp-Silvio` and `www.goal.com/irjnfrfrn-Silvio` in our example) inside a new array.

How would you do it using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, where did you get stuck? What’s the “*[mcve]*” code of your best attempt? What didn’t work, in what way?

Comment: I gotta be honest: while doing unrelated personal stuff, I came up with this problem and I tough a programming language would be useful to solve it.

I'm just starting to learn JS and this seems to be more mid-level or advance task. I did not attempted to solve it myself, but I would love to know how experienced people would approach it.

If this is an inappropriate request, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find where the name part of the URL starts:

```js
const myArray = [
    "www.goal.com/kdñon-BigPussy",
    "www.goal.com/qwñeorkfnvowv-Paulie",
    "www.goal.com/woeknapffflmkub-Tony",
    "www.goal.com/npylhyokhp-Silvio",
    "www.goal.com/irjnfrfrn-Silvio"
];

const groupedByName = myArray.reduce((grouped, url) => {
    const name = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, url.length);
    grouped[name] = grouped[name] || [];
    grouped[name].push(url);
    return grouped;
}, {});

console.log(groupedByName);
const groups = Object.values(groupedByName);
console.log(groups);
```

Comment: This is great, this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Let me ask you: how would you rate this problem according to its difficulty level?

Comment: Just a matter of being exposed to the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) passing a testing function that implements [String.prototype.endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) on each string in the array and returns true or false according the passed string as first argument.

```js
let myArray = [
  "www.goal.com/kdñon-BigPussy", 
  "www.goal.com/qwñeorkfnvowv-Paulie", 
  "www.goal.com/woeknapffflmkub-Tony", 
  "www.goal.com/npylhyokhp-Silvio", 
  "www.goal.com/irjnfrfrn-Silvio"
];

const filteredArray = myArray.filter((url) => url.endsWith('Silvio'))

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: I like this. The only problem is that, if the array contains several strings (let's say hundreds), it would be a lot of effort to manually enter the endings in order to see they are repeated or not.

Thanks anyway, and thanks for your time :)

Comment: You're absolutely right! Sash's idea is better suited and scalable!